# Formating a Function that Returns a Pointer to a Contained Class?

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, containers

I'm trying to use a linked list of pointers to nodes. List is a container class for Node. I'm trying to format a find function for list that returns a pointer to a Node when that node is found in the linked list. However, I keep getting errors saying that there's no type specifier. (Errors are shown in the screenshot linked below, mostly looking at lines 10 and 17 in Node.h). How do I properly format this to get rid of the errors?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uzox.jpg

```
NODE.H //Both class declarations contained here
class list //container class
{
public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void insert(string f, string l, int a);
    node *find(string first, string last); //Pointer to contained class
private:
    node *head; //errors here
    int length;
};
class node
{
    friend list;
public:
    node();                           // Null constructor
    ~node();                          // Destructor 
    void put(ostream &out);           // Put
    bool operator == (const node &);  // Equal
private:
    string first, last;
    node *next;
};

NODE.CPP

#include "Node.h"
   node list::*find(string first, string last) 
    {
        return NULL; //logic not written yet
    }
//MAIN
p = a.find(first, last); //p is a pointer to node, a is a list.
```

Comment: Try `node *list::find(string first, string last) `.

Comment: That doesn't work. It just adds another error

Comment: Maybe, but `node *list::find(string first, string last)` is not valid. Because the return type is `node *` and the function name is `list::find`. You cannot mix them.

Comment: Please paste errors here along with the question. Do not link screenshots. It will give help to better understand your question in one view.

Comment: I just combined your new declaration with the other answers listed below and the errors have cleared!

Answer (score 1):

Right now `node` is defined after `list` and name `node` is not known to compiler when it starts parsing `list` class body. You need to add a forward declaration:

```
class node;

class list
{
...
```

So `node` will be properly recognized a as type name.

Comment: That seems to clear the errors. Just to be clear, that's not going to redefine any variables? And I don't have to move the entire list definition underneath the node definition?

Comment: No, that's not going to redefine anything. Forward declaration only makes `node` recognizable as a type name. Moving entire `list` definition underneath the `node` definition would be an alternative way to fix the error. Note that `friend list;` declaration does not require `list` to be already declared.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that when the compiler compiles the definition of the class `list` it does not know how the name `node` is declared.

There are several ways to resolve the problem. You could use elaborated class names.

For example you could define firstly the class node and use elaborated name of the class list.

```
class node
{
    friend class list;
public:
    node();                           // Null constructor
    ~node();                          // Destructor 
    void put(ostream &out);           // Put
    bool operator == (const node &);  // Equal
private:
    string first, last;
    node *next;
};

class list
{
    //...
};
```

Or you could use elaborated name of the class `node` in the definition of the class `list`. For example

```
class list //container class
{
public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void insert(string f, string l, int a);
    class node *find(string first, string last); //Pointer to contained class
private:
    class node *head;
    int length;
};

class node
{
    //...
};
```

Or you could use a forward declaration of the class `node`.

```
class node;

class list //container class
{
public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void insert(string f, string l, int a);
    node *find(string first, string last); //Pointer to contained class
private:
    node *head;
    int length;
};

class node
{
    //...
};
```

Or you could use a forward declaration of the class `list`.

```
class list;

class node
{
    friend list;
public:
    node();                           // Null constructor
    ~node();                          // Destructor 
    void put(ostream &out);           // Put
    bool operator == (const node &);  // Equal
private:
    string first, last;
    node *next;
};

class list
{
    //...
};
```